# Is that possible to call window procedure from another window trigger section?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to write a program for call window procedure from another window trigger section.Let me share my program what i have tried.

```
DO:
  DEFINE VARIABLE cPartType     AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE cSubPartType  AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE cAttributeExp AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE cOutputQty    AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE cOutputExp    AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE  cResult      AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE  cCheckCase   AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

  ASSIGN
  cPartType     = coCombo  :SCREEN-VALUE IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}  
  cSubPartType  = fiChar-2 :SCREEN-VALUE IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME} 
  cAttributeExp = fiChar-3 :SCREEN-VALUE IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}
  cOutputQty    = fiChar-4 :SCREEN-VALUE IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME} 
  cOutputExp    = fiChar-5 :SCREEN-VALUE IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}.

  { launch.i   &PLIP        = "'ford/prc/Parts.p'"  
                     &IProc       = "'AddPart'"
                     &PList       = "(INPUT cPartType,
                                      INPUT cSubPartType,
                                      INPUT cAttributeExp,
                                      INPUT cOutputQty,
                                      INPUT cOutputExp,
                                      OUTPUT cResult,
                                      OUTPUT cCheckCase)"
                     &AutoKill    =  YES
                     &OnApp       = 'YES'
                     &PARTITION   = 'ASS'                                                                                                   
   }

END.
```

Here I can call the procedure from plipp file but i want to call another window procedure from this trigger. Could you help this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the procedure is in the same program, then just

```
RUN addPart  (INPUT cPartType,
                           INPUT cSubPartType,
                           INPUT cAttributeExp,
                           INPUT cOutputQty,
                           INPUT cOutputExp,
                           OUTPUT cResult,
                           OUTPUT cCheckCase).
```

Now if that procedure lives in a different program, you'll need a handle to it to run. In that case, in the definitions define a handle variable like this

```
DEFINE VARIABLE myHandle AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
```

And in the main block add this code

```
RUN ford/prc/Parts.p PERSISTENT SET myHandle.
```

Finally, in the trigger, do a

```
RUN addPart IN myHandle (INPUT cPartType,
                           INPUT cSubPartType,
                           INPUT cAttributeExp,
                           INPUT cOutputQty,
                           INPUT cOutputExp,
                           OUTPUT cResult,
                           OUTPUT cCheckCase).
```

Comment: Actually what i am trying to say is consider test1.w and test2.w ...In test2.w one procedure called Data..so my point here is i need to call test2.w procedure in test1.w

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying in the second example using the handle. In order for the windows to be aware of each other, you need to have a handle to the program.

Comment: If the windows are launched independently, consider using PUBLISH and SUBSCRIBE. Assuming, of course, they're in the same session. Otherwise, you can only do that by dumping or loading data from external files.